# Distributing the latest revision of a binary in a Git repo without version control

Tags: windows, git, binary, gitlab, git-lfs

I'm tracking a game development project in Git, where I have both source code and compiled binaries that the game needs to run.

Currently, my solution is to track both the source code and the binaries with LFS, because I want to be able to distribute them to other contributors (may be programmers, level designers, artists, etc.) who may just want to run the game, or edit a level or a texture, without forcing them to rebuild and recompile the binaries on every relevant pull.

However, as goes with large binaries on Git, this bloats the repository size and implements superfluous version control; and in this case, any binary merge conflicts can resolved by simply merging the source code and rebuilding it.

I've searched around a lot, but I haven't been able to find a specific solution for my use case. Ultimately, my goal is:

1. The latest compiled binaries (specified by gitattributes or something similar) for each branch are distributed to anyone cloning or pulling the repository without having to recompile the code or the levels.
2. Older revisions of the binaries are not kept in Git, bloating the repository size when I already have version control on the source files.
3. This doesn't require a huge amount of extra work, like creating a new release to upload binaries with every code change; ideally, it takes place behind the scenes, so contributors can interact with the repository normally, like LFS.
4. Works on Windows 10 and GitLab, with minimal dependencies.

I've gathered a few options I can take for this, though none of them are satisfactory.

- gitignoring all of the compiled binaries
      Pros: Don't have to worry about the binaries at all. Push source files without any worries.
      Cons: Whenever someone pulls, they need to make a note of what changed and rebuild anything affected by it. Wastes a lot of time, especially for non-programmers that just want to run the game or make some asset changes.
- Tracking all of the compiled binaries with LFS
      Pros: Everything is pretty clean, and the binaries stay in the repo with the other files so everyone gets a copy.
      Cons: Bloats the repository with unnecessary version control for generated files.
- Storing the compiled binaries in a separate repo and pushing/pulling from that with git hooks; either using a shallow clone or curl with the GitLab API
      Pros: Keeps the binaries isolated off of the main repo, and stays in the background. Seems like my best option so far.
      Cons: Basically just pushes the same problems off into another repo, and feels like reinventing the wheel.
- [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), which I've seen mentioned in similar questions
      Pros: Seems like it should be a solution; [its website](https://git-annex.branchable.com/how_it_works/) mentions how it replaces certain files with pointers kind of like LFS, and that sounds about right.
      Cons: Doesn't seem like it's made for Windows. Complains about a crippled filesystem. Documentation and tutorials seem really sparse, and I can't figure out anything.
- [git-fat](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat), another utility I've seen in similar questions
      Pros: Looks promising based on the readme, although I can't really tell what it's doing.
      Cons: Appears to require a server to host the files on, which I do not have. Also looks like it isn't made for Windows.

I doubt I'm the first person to have this problem, and I feel like I'm missing something. What's the simplest way to deal with compiled binaries like this in a Git collaborative environment?

Comment: IMHO : you are describing a release server ; such a server does not need to be integrated with your git repo, it may be a simple file server, where the link "version <-> commit" is clearly identifiable. You can additionally version a script which allows to download the version which matches `HEAD`.

Comment: @LeGEC I don't have a server to use for that. I do have a website, but that's served by Netlify from GitLab, so it doesn't really count. The best I can think of for this sort of solution is using another repo as the "server", i.e. the third option on my list.

Answer (score 0):

Git repositories aren't designed for tracking binary build artifacts.  As you've seen, this bloats the repository and causes merge conflicts.  You should indeed ignore any build artifacts and make sure they aren't checked into your repository.

As LeGEC suggested in the comments, you want a release server.  This could be a server you maintain (e.g., a VPS with an HTTP server) or a cloud bucket.  If you use a CI system to build and test your builds, sometimes those will host recent versions of build artifacts; GitHub Actions does this, for example.  There are also fancier tools, like Artifactory.

Note that all major hosting providers I'm aware of that support Git LFS charge after a certain amount of data, so hosting your own cloud bucket is probably going to be cheaper (and support pruning a lot better) than Git LFS.

If you do end up checking them into a repository, your hosting provider is going to be unhappy with you because the repository will grow large and maintenance of it will be expensive and slow, so they'll probably ask you to stop doing that at some point.